# How to pass value of multiple checkbox to a model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox

i've in a rails form a multiple checkbox values.
I need to pass this values (if checked) to a model that create the categories.

I've this in form.html_erb

```
<%= form.check_box :categories, {multiple: true}, "U6", nil %>
<%= form.check_box :categories, {multiple: true}, "U8", nil %>
<%= form.check_box :categories, {multiple: true}, "U10", nil %>
```

I want to create TeamCategory with the values checked.
Something like this?

```
def create_tournament_team_categories
    VALUE_CHECKED.each do |name|
      team_category = TeamCategory.where(name: VALUE_CHECKED).first_or_create
      self.tournament_team_categories << TournamentTeamCategory.create(team_category: team_category)
    end
  end
```

Now the TeamCategory are created automatically with this:

```
    def create_tournament_team_categories TeamCategory::NAMES.each do |name| 
team_category = TeamCategory.where(name: name).first_or_create 
self.tournament_team_categories << TournamentTeamCategory.create(team_category: team_category)
    end 
    end
```

And in TeamCategory model i've: 
`NAMES = %w[U6 U8 U10 U12 U14 U16].freeze`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [collection_check_boxes](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_check_boxes) helper:

```
form.collection_check_boxes(:category_ids, TeamCategory.all, :id, :name)
```

`_ids=` is a special setter [created by the `has_many` and HABTM macros](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#module-ActiveRecord::Associations::ClassMethods-label-Collection+associations+-28one-to-many+-2F+many-to-many-29). You just pass an array of ids and rails will handle creating the join records for you.

Just make sure you whitelist the array:

```
params.require(:tournament).permit(:foo, :bar, category_ids: [])
```

Comment: The name of categories is not saved in any table. I want to pass the :name value manually and then create Team Category as the values checked.

Comment: Now the TeamCategory are created automatically with this:

```
 def create_tournament_team_categories
    TeamCategory::NAMES.each do |name|
      team_category = TeamCategory.where(name: name).first_or_create
      self.tournament_team_categories << TournamentTeamCategory.create(team_category: team_category)
    end
  end
```

And in TeamCategory model i've:

```
NAMES = %w[U6 U8 U10 U12 U14 U16].freeze
```

Comment: That sounds like a really overcomplicated solution to a easy problem. If you really want to use a plain array use the check boxes helper and create a array in the params by naming the checkboxes `tournament[category_ids][]`.